# How to access multiple pieces of data from ajax from PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, output

I have this AJAXcode which gets data from a PHP script, how can I set more than one echo variable in PHP and output them separately using AJAX without refreshing staying on the same page?

**AJAX Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //elements
            var progressbox     = $('#progressbox');
            var progressbar     = $('#progressbar');
            var statustxt       = $('#statustxt');
            var submitbutton    = $("#SubmitButton");
            var myform          = $("#UploadForm");
            var output          = $("#ImageOutput");
            var completed       = '0%';

                    $(myform).ajaxForm({
                        beforeSend: function() { //brfore sending form
                            submitbutton.attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
                            statustxt.empty();
                            progressbox.slideDown(); //show progressbar
                            progressbar.width(completed); //initial value 0% of progressbar
                            statustxt.html(completed); //set status text
                            statustxt.css('color','#000'); //initial color of status text
                        },
                        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) { //on progress
                            progressbar.width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
                            statustxt.html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text
                            if(percentComplete>50)
                                {
                                    statustxt.css('color','#fff'); //change status text to white after 50%
                                }
                            },
                        complete: function(response) { // on complete
                            output.html(response.responseText); //update element with received data
                            myform.resetForm();  // reset form
                            submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
                            progressbox.slideUp(); // hide progressbar
                        },
                });
            });
```

**PHP Code**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_GET))
{
     //Some Settings
    $BigImageMaxSize        = 300; //Image Maximum height or width
    $DestinationDirectory   = 'uploads/'; //Upload Directory ends with / (slash)
    $Quality                = 80;

    // check $_FILES['ImageFile'] array is not empty
    // "is_uploaded_file" Tells whether the file was uploaded via HTTP POST
    if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']))
    {
            die('Something went wrong with Upload!'); // output error when above checks fail.
    }

    // Random number for both file, will be added after image name
    $RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999);

    // Elements (values) of $_FILES['ImageFile'] array
    //let's access these values by using their index position
    $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']));
    $ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; // Obtain original image size
    $TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']; // Tmp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
    $ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //Obtain file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.



    //Let's use $ImageType variable to check wheather uploaded file is supported.
    //We use PHP SWITCH statement to check valid image format, PHP SWITCH is similar to IF/ELSE statements
    //suitable if we want to compare the a variable with many different values




    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
        case 'image/jpg':
            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
    }



    //PHP getimagesize() function returns height-width from image file stored in PHP tmp folder.
    //Let's get first two values from image, width and height. list assign values to $CurWidth,$CurHeight
    list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);
    //Get file extension from Image name, this will be re-added after random name
    $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
    $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);


    //remove extension from filename
    $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);

    //Construct a new image name (with random number added) for our new image.
    $NewImageName = 'IMG-'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;
    //set the Destination Image
    $DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName; //Name for Big Image



    //Resize image to our Specified Size by calling resizeImage function.
    if(resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
    {






        /*
        At this point we have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
        We can render image to user's browser or store information in the database
        For demo, we are going to output results on browser.
        */

        //Get New Image Size
        list($ResizedWidth,$ResizedHeight)=getimagesize($DestRandImageName);

        $ImageURL = '<img src="uploads/'.$NewImageName.'" class="imageUploaded" height="'.$ResizedHeight.'" width="'.$ResizedWidth.'">';


        echo $ImageURL;



    }else{
        die('Resize Error'); //output error
    }



}
 $_SESSION['varname'] = $NewImageName;


// This function will proportionally resize image
function resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$MaxSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Construct a proportional size of new image
    $ImageScale         = min($MaxSize/$CurWidth, $MaxSize/$CurHeight);
    $NewWidth           = ceil($ImageScale*$CurWidth);
    $NewHeight          = ceil($ImageScale*$CurHeight);

    if($CurWidth < $NewWidth || $CurHeight < $NewHeight)
    {
        $NewWidth = $CurWidth;
        $NewHeight = $CurHeight;
    }

    $NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);
    // Resize Image
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $CurWidth, $CurHeight))
    {
        switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    //Destroy image, frees up memory
    if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);}
    return true;
    }
}
//This function corps image to create exact square images, no matter what its original size!
function cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$iSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //abeautifulsite.net has excellent article about "Cropping an Image to Make Square"
    //http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2009/08/cropping-an-image-to-make-square-thumbnails-in-php/
    if($CurWidth>$CurHeight)
    {
        $y_offset = 0;
        $x_offset = ($CurWidth - $CurHeight) / 2;
        $square_size    = $CurWidth - ($x_offset * 2);
    }else{
        $x_offset = 0;
        $y_offset = ($CurHeight - $CurWidth) / 2;
        $square_size = $CurHeight - ($y_offset * 2);
    }

    $NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($iSize, $iSize);
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, $x_offset, $y_offset, $iSize, $iSize, $square_size, $square_size))
    {
        switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

    //Destroy image, frees up memory
    if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);}
    return true;

    }

}   
?>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="processupload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadForm">
<table width="500" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>File : </td>
    <td><input name="ImageFile" type="file" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit"  id="SubmitButton" value="Upload" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id="progressbox"><div id="progressbar"></div><div id="statustxt">0%</div ></div>
<div id="ImageOutput"></div>
```

Comment: is this question still active? if it isn't then please mark an answer. if it is then I'll take a shot at it

Answer (score 1):

I usual use a JSON to transmit more than 1 info.

**Example**

Here a ajax jQuery (see [http://jquery.org/](https://jquery.org/)) expecting a JSON:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

            $.ajax({
                url:'/some/script.php',
                type:'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                'timeout':15000,
                'success': function (data) {
                    if(data.esito == 'OK'){
                        // do something
                    } else {
                        alert(data.message);

                    }
                }
            });
</script>
```

The *script.php* can be as follow. Nothe that I build a PHP array then I transform it in a JSON:

```
<?php
  // do something
  $response = array(
    'esito' => 'OK',
    'message' => 'message',
    'imageUrl' => '/images/1.jpg',
    'size' => 12345,
  );

  echo json_encode($response);
die();
?>
```